# Convert a lists that is a bytes into a list of ints

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to convert a bytes list into a list of `int`, the data that I'm pulling resemble:

```
test = b'[[9126, 0.2812168002128601], [9514, 0.2675456404685974], [9342, 0.26063060760498047], [8999, 0.23802196979522705], [9056, 0.23092836141586304], [9053, 0.22339123487472534], [9019, 0.2215365171432495], [9225, 0.21875709295272827]]
```

when I run `str(test, "utf-8")` or `test.decode("utf-8")` it converts `test` into a long string. I need to convert `test` into a list so that I could iterate through it, where

```
test[0] = [9126, 0.2812168002128601]
test[1] = [9514, 0.2675456404685974]
...
```

wheres now I get:

```
test[0] = [
test[1] = [
test[2] = 9
...
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import json
>>> test = b'[[9126, 0.2812168002128601], [9514, 0.2675456404685974], [9342, 0.26063060760498047], [8999, 0.23802196979522705], [9056, 0.23092836141586304], [9053, 0.22339123487472534], [9019, 0.2215365171432495], [9225, 0.21875709295272827]]'
>>> new_list = json.loads(test)
>>> new_list
[[9126, 0.2812168002128601], [9514, 0.2675456404685974], [9342, 0.26063060760498047], [8999, 0.23802196979522705], [9056, 0.23092836141586304], [9053, 0.22339123487472534], [9019, 0.2215365171432495], [9225, 0.21875709295272827]]
>>> new_list[0]
[9126, 0.2812168002128601]
>>> new_list[1]
[9514, 0.2675456404685974]
```